# Renice all of the processes

Tags: mac

My Mac somehow lags when I connect to an external monitor. (Apple Thunderbolt display).

I think a lot of background processes and apps (which are essential) are causing a lot of lag and painfulness.

I'm planning to run this (to make all processes nice, so that none of them will block):

```
sudo renice -n 20  -p $(ps aux  | awk '{print $2}')
```

Would I cause any harm if I do that?

If I could find out which program can help reduce lag then I could probably give it a lower niceness. But I don't know which one.

**Edit**

```
renice -n 20  -p $(pgrep Mail)
renice -n 20  -p $(pgrep Ma)
renice -n 20  -p $(pgrep dbeaver)
renice -n 20  -p $(pgrep WindowServer)
renice -n 20  -p $(pgrep TextEdit)
renice -n 20  -p $(pgrep Terminal)
renice -n 20  -p $(pgrep Safari)
renice -n 20  -p $(pgrep Google)
renice -n 20  -p $(pgrep corespotlightd)
renice -n 20  -p $(pgrep SuperBrowser)
renice -n 20  -p $(pgrep Dropbox)
renice -n 20  -p $(pgrep Helper)
renice -n 20  -p $(pgrep FireFox)
renice -n 20  -p $(pgrep fire)
```

I temporarily did this above. It seems the lagging issue is a better.. Now my Mac could open Mail (with 10 email address) and Dropbox and connected to Thunderbolt without lagging too much....

Comment: If you change the scheduling priority of *all* processes, their priority relative to each other doesn't change so I doubt you see any benefit out of this. Matters may even get worse because processes which already *have* lower priority will have the same priority as every other process afterwards.

Comment: This is a very bad idea and I think you need to check your premise that 'a lot of background processes are causing lag'. How much CPU is being used by all these processes?

Comment: @benwiggy, peak is 20-30% after I did the above renice. previously it would be 50-70%....

Comment: I think the computer did too high priority background re-index and maintenance, causing the lag...

Comment: @nohillside, the idea for me is that, I want to lower all the priority of all the process, except some, which can improve user lagness experience....

Comment: Well, just try then, don‘t think it will break anything (nor do I think it will help). It‘s a bit like destroying and rebuilding a house just because a window is broken :-)

Comment: yea... but the lagging had made my life very hard, and i don't want to keep open and close important apps... Otherwise, i may miss important email/ dropbox didn't backup my important work files....

Comment: So work out what is causing the lag and fix that